# Is it possible to refer to a collection of definitions in JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am constructing a schema using JSON-schema, part of which describes mathematical operations (such as add, multiply, subtract, divide, etc).

These operations can take operands that are variables, but they can also take instances of themselves. That is `"add"` and `"multiply"` types may be represented as follows:

```
"add": {
    "description": "The mathematical operation of adding two or more operands together",
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 2,
    "items": {
        "anyOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/variable" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/subformula" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/add" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/multiply" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/subtract" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/divide" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/sum" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/maximum" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/average" }
        ]
    }
},
"multiply": {
    "description": "The mathematical operation of multiplying two or more operands together",
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 2,
    "items": {
        "anyOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/variable" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/subformula" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/add" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/multiply" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/subtract" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/divide" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/sum" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/maximum" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/average" }
        ]
    }
}
```

For JSON such as:

```
"add": [ 5, 6, "multiply": [ 2, 3 ] ]
```

This list of type references is similar for every operation and sub-formula. This is rather cumbersome in the case that more operations might be added they need to be added to this list at every place that the list occurs...

Is it possible to somehow markup the operations such that I could refer to them as a group, something like the following:

```
"add": {
    "description": "The mathematical operation of adding two or more operands together",
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 2,
    "items": {
        "anyOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/variable" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/subformula" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/operations/" } //note the trailing '/'
        ]
    }
},
"multiply": {
    "description": "The mathematical operation of multiplying two or more operands together",
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 2,
    "items": {
        "anyOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/variable" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/subformula" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/operations/" } //note the trailing '/'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Formulating you an answer now. Totally possible and easy! =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using `definitions`. The value of a key in the `definitions` key word must be a JSON Schema. As such, you can combine `anyOf` and `$ref` similar to how you have done already.

> The "definitions" keywords provides a standardized location for schema
> authors to inline re-usable JSON Schemas into a more general schema.
> The keyword does not directly affect the validation result.
>
> This keyword's value MUST be an object. Each member value of this
> object MUST be a valid JSON Schema.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-9

```
"items": {
  "$ref": "#/definitions/myOtherGroup",
}

...

"definitions": {
  "operations": {
    "anyOf": [
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/add" },
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/multiply" },
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/subtract" },
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/divide" },
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/sum" },
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/maximum" },
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/average" }
    ]
  }
  "myOtherGroup": {
    "anyOf": [
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/variable" },
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/subformula" },
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/operations" },
    ]
  }
}
```

You would just need to change the name of "myOtherGroup" to whatever you want to call it. I'm assuming your other definitions are already there but you just didn't include them in your question (which is fine for this purpose).

Comment: Curious to know if this simply didn't occur to you, or if there's something missing from the spec we can add to make this clearer. Feel free to join the JSON Schema Slack to discuss =]

Comment: Thanks lots! It did occur but I'm pretty new to JSON and JS in general, so I've been going mostly doing spot checks with online validators - unfortunately the latter appear to choke when there is lots of circular references. Currently in the process of creating an minimised example to test such things with. TBH I don't find the standard hugely readable, it's very technical. But the excellent spacetelescope site helps a lot

Comment: Welcome! Yeah, it's a common issue; the spec is designed with implementors and users in mind, but if you're not familiar with reading RFC documents, it's hard reading! The spacetelescope site is great, but not up to date, and not maintained, so be careful. We would love to create some nice guides, but it's very time consuming! - I tend to use https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net for checking. I've not had many issues.